# Problem on attach a file with PHP mail() function and read that file from downloading the mail

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am sending a mail with the attachemnet using the PHP mail function.I suceessfully attached the document to mail and I got it in the mail.My problem is when I try to read the document I got an error.If I downloaded the document and open the document I cant the see the text in the  attached document.Here is the coding...

```
$fileatt = '../'.$_POST['path']; // Path to the file
  $fileatt_type = "application/octet-sdiveam"; // File Type
  $fileatt_name = $_POST['attachfile']; 
  $email_from = 'admin@mydomain.com'; // Who the email is from
  $email_subject = $_POST['Subject']; // The Subject of the email
  $email_txt = $_POST['Subject']; // Message that the email has in it

  $email_to = $_POST['To']; // Who the email is to

   $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

  $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
  fclose($file);

  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-divansfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $email_message . "\n\n";

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

  $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  "Content-divansfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
  $data . "\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";


  $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Is it the correct way?Why i can't read the document?I dont know.Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED:**

Problem is spelling mistake.
    **Content-divansfer-Encoding:** Should be **Content-Transfer-Encoding:**

Comment: Try `echo $email_message;` to see the built string, and add it to the question.

Comment: You should really try and use one of the better mailer libraries out there, instead of reinventing the wheel. My 2 cents. Personally I've been using this: http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/Rmail/Rmail%20for%20PHP/

Comment: @kitsched I used that one.It displays the message the mail is sent.But after one hour also I didnt get anything(mail,attachment).

Comment: Now I got the mail.But in the attached document nothing is there.I dont know why?

Comment: One small error make this error.That is spelling mistake.If you see the `Content-divansfer-Encoding` it should be `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.Thats all.Issue Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended using pear's mail and mail_mime libraries to make this process significantly easier and cleaner.